# Build failed after upgrade react native to 0.44 v

Tags: android, react-native, compilation, upgrade

I just upgraded react native to 0.44.0 version and I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

    Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

And Android Studio's Event log :

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :react-native-navigation:generateDebugSources, :react-native-navigation:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :react-native-navigation:mockableAndroidJar, :react-native-navigation:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :realm:generateDebugSources, :realm:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :realm:mockableAndroidJar, :realm:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
```

Need some help with that ! Thanks !

Environment

```
React Native Navigation version: 1.1.65
React Native version: 0.44.0
Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): Android
Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): AVD from Android Studio (6.0 API 23) and tested with a second AVD (7.1.1 API 25) => got same build failed
```

EDIT 1 :

Here my pacakage.json

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-native": "^0.44.0",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.65",
    "realm": "^1.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

EDIT 2 :

I finally updated my build.gradle app to 25 compileSdkVersion from 23 and the buildToolsVersion to '25.0.2' from '23.x.x'.

```
 android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

It compiled and I can run my app again for now.

Comment: Hi can u share the github repo of React Native Navigation you are using. I face same problem with my react native projects and its always because of inter dependencies. In your case it looks like React Native Navigation depends on a lower version of React Native. So either update your React Native Navigation or downgrade the React Native, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, 
I am using this package: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation

And I tried both upgrade and downgrade RN or RNN but no success yet...

Comment: Thats what i thought u were using, i got confused looking at the version you mentioned 4.2.0, latest is unstable v2.0.1 like 35 mins ago. Try this, remove all ^ from package.json file, they mean auto upgrade dependency if available (always leads to conflicts). Delete node_modules folder and run npm install. You will see error logs stating the version causing conflicts. PS clone your project in a separate folder and do this. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ok so, I tried to do the changes you mentionned and I get theses errors after 'npm install' : `npm WARN react-test-renderer@15.5.4 requires a peer of react@^15.5.0 but none was installed.`
`npm WARN The package react-test-renderer is included as both a dev and production dependency.`

I tried to run again and get this error : `Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt`

I finally update my build.gradle app to 25 compileSdkVersion from 23 and the buildToolsVersion to '25.0.2' from '23.x.x'. It compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using automatic installation solved my pb